# How to tcl print control characters

Tags: tcl

How do I print something repeatedly on the same line?
I.e. a percent down-counter until some proc is done?
I wish that on the xterm line the percent numbers are counting down without scrolling.

If I do

```
puts -nonewline "10%"
puts -nonewline "9%"
puts -nonewline "8%"
puts -nonewline "7%"
```

I get:

```
10%9%8%7%....
```

That doesn't look right.

What's the trick?

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: May be the `term` package can help?

Answer (score 2):

You want a carriage return to send the cursor to the start of the line:

```
for {set i 10} {$i>0} {incr i -1} {
    puts -nonewline [format "\r%2d%%" $i]
    flush stdout
    after 200
}; puts ""
```

Comment: Remember to add one or several spaces at the end of the output string. Otherwise you'll end up with "10%" then "9%%" then "8%%" etc.